# How to load external html file in a template in VueJs

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, vue-router

I'm new to vue js. 
I'm just creating  a simple project where I just include vuejs through CDN. not using node/npm or cli.

I keep all my html markup in single html which looks messy as it grows. I tried to split html to views and want to include it by something analogous to `ng-include` of angularJs

I have worked in angular previously where there is `ng-include` to load external html files. I'm looking for something similar to that in vue. the whole point is to split my html files into more maintainable separate files.

have come across `<template src="./myfile.html"/>` but it doesn't work
Can somebody help me out

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's actually remarkably easy, but you need to keep something in mind. Behind the scenes, Vue converts your html template markup to code. That is, each element you see defined as HTML, gets converted to a javascript directive to create an element. The template is a convenience, so the single-file-component (vue file) is not something you'll be able to do without compiling with something like webpack. Instead, you'll need to use some other way of templating. Luckily there are other ways of defining templates that don't require pre-compiling and are useable in this scenario.

### 1 - string/template literals

example: `template: '<div>{{myvar}}</div>'`

### 2 - render function

example: `render(create){create('div')}`

Vue has several other ways of creating templates, but they just don't match the criteria.

here is the example for both:

AddItem.js - using render  functions

```js
'use strict';
Vue.component('add-item', {
  methods: {
    add() {
      this.$emit('add', this.value);
      this.value = ''
    }
  },

  data () {
    return {
      value: ''
    }
  },

  render(createElement) {
    var self = this
    return createElement('div', [
      createElement('input', {
        attrs: {
          type: 'text',
          placeholder: 'new Item'
        },
        // v-model functionality has to be implemented manually
        domProps: {
          value: self.value
        },
        on: {
          input: function (event) {
            self.value = event.target.value
            // self.$emit('input', event.target.value)
          }
        }
      }),
      createElement('input', {
        attrs: {
          type: 'submit',
          value: 'add'
        },
        on: {
          click: this.add
        }
      }),
    ])
  }
});
```

ListItem.js - using template literals (back-ticks)

```js
'use strict';
Vue.component('list-item', {
  template: `<div class="checkbox-wrapper" @click="check">
    <h1>{{checked ? '☑' : '☐'}} {{ title }}</h1>
  </div>`,
  props: [
    'title',
    'checked'
  ],
  methods: {
    check() {
      this.$emit('change', !this.checked);
    }
  }
});
```

and the html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.4.0/vue.js"></script>
  <script src="ListItem.js"></script>
  <script src="AddItem.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="app">
  <add-item @add='list.push({title:arguments[0], checked: false})'></add-item>
  <list-item v-for="(l, i) in list" :key="i" :title="l.title" :checked="l.checked" @change="l.checked=arguments[0]"></list-item>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    newTitle: '',
    list: [
      { title: 'A', checked: true },
      { title: 'B', checked: true },
      { title: 'C', checked: true }
    ]
  }
});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

## TL; DR;

### See it in action at : https://repl.it/OEMt/9

Comment: And is there a way to compile my HTML files into render function with, say, a makefile?

Answer (score 3):

You cant. You must use async components - read guide [here](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#Async-Components)

Answer (score 1):

Actually you can. This is kinda easy. Depends on your needs and situation. However, **this code is NOT technically correct**, however it will explain to you how it might work, gives you massive freedom and makes your original vue instance smaller.

To make this work, you will need vue router (cdn is ok) and in this case axios or fetch (if you dont care about supporting older browsers).

The only downfall in my opinion is that in content files you will need to add additional call parameter **$parent** . This will force vue to work.

**index**

```
<div id="app">

  <router-link v-for="route in this.$router.options.routes" :to="route.path" :key="route.path">{{ route.name }}</router-link>

  <section style="margin-top:50px;">
     <component :is="magician && { template: magician }" />
  </section>

</div>

  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue/dist/vue.js"></script>
  <script src="https://unpkg.com/vue-router/dist/vue-router.js"></script>
  <script src="https://unpkg.com/axios/dist/axios.min.js"></script>

  <script>
     const viewer = axios.create({ baseURL: location.origin });

     const routes = [
       {"name":"Hello","slug":"hello","path":"/lol/index.html"},
       {"name":"Page One","slug":"page_one","path":"/lol/page-one.html"},
       {"name":"Page Two","slug":"page_two","path":"/lol/page-two.html"}
     ];

     const app = new Vue({
       router,
       el: '#app',
       data: {
          magician: null,
       },
       watch: {
          $route (to) {
              this.loader(to.path);
          }
       },
       mounted() {
          this.loader(this.$router.currentRoute.path);
       },
       methods: {
          viewer(opt) {
              return viewer.get(opt);
          },
          loader(to) {
              to == '/lol/index.html' ? to = '/lol/hello.html' : to = to;
              this.viewer(to).then((response) => {
                  this.magician = response.data;
              }).catch(error => {
                  alert(error.response.data.message);
              })
          },
          huehue(i) {
            alert(i);
          }
       }
     });
  </script>
```

**hello.html content**

```
<button v-on:click="$parent.huehue('this is great')">Button</button>
```

**page-one.html content**

```
<select>
   <option v-for="num in 20">{{ num }}</option>
</select>
```

**page-two.html content**

```
// what ever you like
```

**router explanation**

To make this work perfectly, you will need to find a correct way to configure your htaccess to render everything if current page after first view is not index. Everything else should work fine.

As you can see, if it is index, it will load hello content file.

Answer (score 1):

I faced the same issue and this is how I solved it  , I also made a video about this question [https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=J037aiMGGAw](https://youtu.be/J037aiMGGAw)

1. create a js file ,for your component (logic) let's call it "aaaa.vue.js"
2. create an HTML file for your template that will be injected in your "aaaa.vue.js" and let's call it "aaaa.html"

### Component file (Logic file javascript)

```
const aaaa = {
  name:"aaaa",
  template: ``,
  data() {
    return {
      foo:"aaaa"
    };
  },    
  methods: {
    async test() {
      alert(this.foo)
    },
  },
};
```

---

### Template file  (HTML)

```
<!--template file-->
<div>
  <button @click="test" > click me plz </button>
</div>
```

---

### index.html

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title>my app</title>
  </head>

  <body>
    <div id="app" class="main-content col-12">
      <aaaa></aaaa>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>

<script src="axios.min.js"></script>
<script src="vue.js"></script>

<!-- load js file (logic) -->
<script src="aaaa.vue.js"></script>

<script>
  document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", async function () {
    //register components
    let html = await axios.get("aaaa.html"); // <---- Load HTML file
    aaaa.template = html.data;
    Vue.component("aaaa", aaaa);

    new Vue({
      el: "#app",
      name: "main",
      //... etc
    });
  });
</script>
```

---

Update :
I also created an example on github to see it in action

https://github.com/nsssim/Vue-CDN-load-component

[image]

Answer (score -1):

Sure you can, this is the way we are doing it in all our components of our app.

```
<template src="../templates/the_template.html"></template>

<script>
export default {
    name: 'ComponentName',
    props: {},
    computed: {},
    methods: {},
};
</script>

<style lang="scss">
@import '../styles/myscss_file';
</style>
```

Will need to add

```
runtimeCompiler: true
```

to your vue.config.js file. That's it.