# Include traditional html/js files into an existing vue project

Tags: vuejs2, vue-router

I have a vue project setup which is working fine. I have a set of html/js/files (written by some other person, not using vue) that I want to inlcude in my project.
The layout is like -

```
-> external.html (includes js and css also within it)
-> external2.html (includes js and css also within it)
-> etc.
```

Now in my vue-component, when I click on a link, the vue router should direct it to external.html file and the css/js present in the external.html file must get executed.

How can I do that without rewriting the whole code to make it vue-compatible?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to load external html file in a template in VueJs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47078315/how-to-load-external-html-file-in-a-template-in-vuejs)

Comment: I saw that answer but I don't think that can solve my problem. My external html files contains both html and javascript. I can import the html as template but what do i do about the javascript (written in plain js, not using vue)? How do I load that with minimum refactoring.